# Best method to call a C function from python code

Tags: python, c

I have some C code which has some basic functions. I want to be able to call these C functions from my python code. There seem to be a lot f methods to do this as I search online, but they look a bit complicated. Can anyone suggest which is the simplest and best method to call C functions from python without any issues ?

Comment: This question is open-ended and will lead to subjective answers and as such is a poor fit for stackoverflow.  You may wish to ask your question at [comp.lang.python](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.python).

Comment: Take a look at cython

Answer (score 2):

Cffi library is a fairly modern approach to this. It also works across python and pypy.

Provided you have your functions contained in a shared library, you can just import them as python methods. Have a look at examples here: http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html

Comment: you're linking to a bad part of the docs, ABI level is really dangerous and should be avoided (unless you have no other choice). You don't know the library nor operating system of the author of the question

Comment: It may be dangerous, it may be ok. The document lists all kinds of ways to access the library. I stripped the specific anchor to abi, but exactly because the author didn't specify it, it's as valid answer as any other way. (I mean, they will have to make the choice in the end since we lack details.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared library using the C compiler and make the calls of the functions that are defined in the library, to this, you can use the module CPython.

Comment: Your two sentences are true, but they have no logical relation to each other.  Your answer does not help the OP solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to extend Python with some C functions you can check out the following example. What you need is a module which registers wrapper functions for your own functions.

For more information check out the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#keyword-parameters-for-extension-functions).

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
yourfunction(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *keywds)
{
    int voltage;
    char *state = "a stiff";
    char *action = "voom";
    char *type = "Norwegian Blue";

    static char *kwlist[] = {"voltage", "state", "action", "type", NULL};

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, keywds, "i|sss", kwlist,
                                     &voltage, &state, &action, &type))
        return NULL;

    printf("-- This parrot wouldn't %s if you put %i Volts through it.\n",
           action, voltage);
    printf("-- Lovely plumage, the %s -- It's %s!\n", type, state);

    Py_INCREF(Py_None);

    return Py_None;
}

static PyMethodDef keywdarg_methods[] = {
    {"yourfunction", (PyCFunction)yourfunction, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS,
     "the doc of your function"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}   /* sentinel */
};


// in Python 2.x the function name initmodulename is executed when imported
void initkeywdarg(void)
{
  /* Create the module and add the functions */
  Py_InitModule("keywdarg", keywdarg_methods);
}
```

To compile the file you can use clang. Keep in mind that you have to correct the include path if the Python headers are located somewhere else. The created binary `keywdarg.so` can be created by using `import keywdarg`.

> clang++ -shared -I/usr/include/python2.7 -fPIC keywdarg.cpp -o keywdarg.so -lpython

Answer (score -1):

Let's say your c code sends email, and the code accept args like this

```
./sendemail email title body
```

Then from python , you can do something like:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["./sendemail", "email@email.com", "subject", "body"])
```

Comment: This isn't really integration with C in any meaningful sense.  This is just calling a compiled program with command line arguments.  Everything must be converted to and from strings for this to work.  This *may* be a viable option depending on the OP's needs, but I think you are missing the mark.

Comment: I wrote this method because OP doesn't seem to be knowledgeable enough to import c code into python and run it.

Comment: @taesu that's why he asked the question - hope you're not implying he can't learn new things ;)

Comment: So I don't expect him to import c into python, thus this way seemed relatively eaiser. @viraptor I wasn't and I certainly hope you weren't